# MongoDB define collection that has an array as document

Tags: mongodb

I'm a newbie to `mongodb` and I'm trying to create my first database.

This is my scenario: A user can connect to a `FTP Location` and get/put some files. Each user can have more than one FTP Storage that he can access.

These are the fields required for the `user` document:

```
username: String  
password: String
```

And these are the fields required for the `ftp` document:

```
host: String  
port: Number  
user: String  
pass: String
```

And here comes my question...Can I have a single `collection` that contains both documents mentioned above?

More precisely, I need to know how I can get a record like this and how my database should look...

```
{
    "username": "User",  
    "password": "test",
    [
      {
        "host": "first-host",  
        "port": 21,  
        "user": "defined-user",  
        "pass": "defined-pass"
      },
      {
        "host": "second-host",  
        "port": 21,  
        "user": "defined-user",  
        "pass": "defined-pass"
      }
    ]
}
```

Not sure if my question is clearly enough, but please let me know if I need to specify additional information to get some answers

Comment: Please start here and keep hitting "next" until you actually read it to the end and understood it: [Query Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/)

Comment: I read it and querying the documents is pretty straightforward, but I need to know how I can define a collection that accepts documents with array fields like shown in my example..

Comment: *"8 minutes! Please teach me how to read and learn like you. I expect you to answer everyone's questions from now on. That's fantastic."* Now we are back to reality. Do yourself a real favour and spend some real time learning and testing the examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongo uses json format, so you can have something like that :

```
  "username": "User",
  "password": "test",
  "storage": [
    {
      "host": "first-host",
      "port": 21,
      "user": "defined-user",
      "pass": "defined-pass"
    },
    {
      "host": "second-host",
      "port": 21,
      "user": "defined-user",
      "pass": "defined-pass"
    }
  ]
```

And you shema should be defined like this :

```
username: String  
password: String
storage : Array
```

Comment: Nice! That's all I wanted to know

Answer (score 0):

BSON documents are basically JSON/JS objects (with a few additional types). So, your mongodb document **MUST** be a valid json/js object. The desired document shape from your question is not valid js object and, as such, is impossible in mongodb.

Comment: I edited my question and now the document shape is a valid js object.

Comment: @Valip: no, it's not. Read up on what JS objects are (can be)

Comment: Edited again :)